# \label referenced does'nt work in only enviroment using pgfplots

Tags: beamer, only

I'm really stuck on the following problem. I have an image with a lot of curves and for this reason, I want to plot their step by step using \only. I have also a \label in order to write it in a legend. But when I recall it, it's doesn't work. I read from the beamer documentation that the correct definition of \label in only is:

> \only{some text.\label{my_label}}

But also in this way the code doesn't work, any tips?

```
\begin{frame}{Risultati, Correlazioni a un punto, Primo Ordine}
 \pause
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
 Effetti numero di Richardson
     \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.95]
    \begin{axis}[width=\columnwidth, xlabel={$y/R$}, ylabel={$\overline{U_z}$}]
            \only<3->{\addplot[color = black, line width=0.8 pt]
            table[x index = 6, y index = 3]{./data/RE_180/forced/profiles.txt};}
            \only<4->{\addplot[color = green, line width=0.8 pt]
            table[x index = 6, y index = 3]{./data/RE_180/ri17/profiles.txt};}
           \only<5->{\addplot[color = cyan, line width=0.8 pt]
            table[x index = 6, y index = 3]{./data/RE_180/ri40/profiles.txt};
            \addplot[color = blue, line width=0.8 pt]
            table[x index = 6, y index = 3]{./data/RE_180/ri87/profiles.txt};
            \addplot[color = red, line width=0.8 pt]
            table[x index = 6, y index = 3, ]{./data/RE_180/ri241/profiles.txt};}
            \only<6->{\addplot[color = black, mark= o, mark size = 2 pt, only marks , mark phase =1, mark repeat =3]
            table[x index = 0, y index = 1]{./data/RE_180/forced/profiles_el.txt};
            \addplot[color = green, mark=o, only marks, mark size = 2 pt, mark repeat =3]
                table[x index = 0, y index = 1]{./data/RE_180/ri17/ri17.txt};
            \addplot[color = cyan, mark=o, only marks, mark size = 2 pt, mark repeat =3]
                table[x index = 0, y index = 1]{./data/RE_180/ri40/ri40.txt};
            \addplot[color = blue, mark=o, only marks, mark size = 2 pt, mark repeat =3]
                table[x index = 0, y index = 1]{./data/RE_180/ri87/ri87.txt};
            \addplot[color = red, mark=o, only marks, mark size = 2 pt, mark repeat =3]
                table[x index = 0, y index = 1]{./data/RE_180/ri241/ri241.txt};}
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\only<7->{Effetti numero di Reynolds
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.95]
\begin{axis}[width=\columnwidth, xlabel={$y/R$}, ylabel={$\overline{U_z}$}]
            \only<8->{\addplot[color = black, line width=0.8 pt]
            table[x index = 6, y index = 3]{./data/RE_180/forced/profiles.txt};
            \addplot[color = green, line width=0.8 pt]
            table[x index = 6, y index = 3]{./data/RE_180/ri17/profiles.txt};
            \addplot[color = cyan, line width=0.8 pt]
            table[x index = 6, y index = 3]{./data/RE_180/ri40/profiles.txt};
            \addplot[color = blue, line width=0.8 pt]
            table[x index = 6, y index = 3]{./data/RE_180/ri87/profiles.txt};
            \addplot[color = red, line width=0.8 pt]
            table[x index = 6, y index = 3, ]{./data/RE_180/ri241/profiles.txt};}
            \only<9>{\addplot[color = black, line width=0.8 pt, dashed]
            table[x index = 6, y index = 3]{./data/RE_360/forced/profiles.txt};\label{black_d}        
        \addplot[color = green, line width=0.8 pt,dashed]
            table[x index = 6, y index = 3]{./data/RE_360/ri17/profiles.txt}; 
        \addplot[color = cyan, line width=0.8 pt,dashed]
            table[x index = 6, y index = 3]{./data/RE_270/ri40/profiles.txt};
        \addplot[color = black, line width=0.8 pt, dashed]
            table[x index = 6, y index = 3]{./data/RE_360/ri87/profiles.txt};
        \addplot[color = red, line width=0.8 pt,dashed]
            table[x index = 6, y index = 3]{./data/RE_360/ri241/profiles.txt};}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
 \only<2->{Profilo di velocità assiale medio.} \only<3->{Ri 0 (\ref{Forced}),} \only<4->{Ri 0.017 (\ref{ri17}),} \only<5->{Ri 0.040 (\ref{ri40}), Ri 0.087 (\ref{ri87}), Ri 0.241 (\ref{ri241}),} \only<6->{$Re_\tau \; 180$ (\ref{Forced}), DNS di riferimento ($\circ$),} \only<9>{$Re_\tau \; 360$ (\ref{black_d}).}
\end{frame}
```

The \ref{black_d} isn't defined according to the program, and I don't understand why.
Unfortunately, I can't upload the data. But the result that I obtain is shown in the images. As shown, the reference for Re_\tau 360 in unknown.
[image]

Comment: Is this copy pasted? Cause you're missing a } in "\only<7->{Effetti numero di Reynolds" by the looks of it.

Comment: Yes is copy pasted. The } missing is after \end{figure}

Comment: posting code that people can not use is not so helpful. It would be better to reference a data file in the current directory and post _complete_ test file and a small complete data file so peopel can see your issue.

Comment: but your question is not very clear. There is no connection other than accidental english name similarity beween the `ylabel` key (refering to the printed labels on the axis) and the `\label` command which does not affect printing at all and gives the internal key for cross referencing.

Comment: Ah, I see. But wouldn't that mean that the whole figure is defined as the label? Or am I misunderstanding \only{......\label<{same number}>{my_label}}. Wouldn't you have \only{\label<number>{label}\begin{figure}...\end{figure}} ??

Comment: `\label`  references a referencable counter such as a section or equation counter. I don't see any such counter here but as you have only posted a fragment that we can't run, it is hard to say.

Comment: My apologies, it's the first time that I use this forum. I try to reupload the question and the code in a better way

Comment: This is only a wild guess.  `\ref{black_d}` contains an underscore character.  Although it should probably work, it's the only label containing an underscore, and it's something I wouldn't do, because I associate `_` too strongly with math mode, and use it only there.  Try a hyphen instead, and see if that improves things.